# What is the solar window (solar altitude angle range) of Bangalore?

Tags: solar-energy

What is the solar altitude at Bangalore at solar noon during summer solstice, March equinox, Winter solstice and September equinox? In other words, What is the solar window (solar altitude angle range) of Bangalore?

PS: Consider latitude of Bangalore to be 11 deg, North.

Comment: There are websites for this - have you looked?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more appropriate to astronomy.SE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earth axial tilt is 23.5°. For 11°N the solar altitude at noon of the equinoxes will be 90-11=79°; 90-11-23.5=55.5° at winter solstice and - it would be 90-11+23.5=102.5° at the summer solstice, but we normalize it to angle between nearest horizon and the Sun, so for values >90 we take 180-(value): 180-102.5=77.5° at the summer solstice.

The actual solar window though will be the range between minimum and maximum altitude: 55.5°-90° as the Sun passes through Zenith sometime in the late spring and early summer.